# mdpdf closes batch script

Tags: batch-file, pdf, npm

I have a batch script that that uses [mdpdf](https://npmjs.com/package/mdpdf). I use the command `mdpdf FILE_NAME.md FOLDER/DIFFERENT_FILE_NAME.pdf`, and after that I have a few more batch commands. My script looks like this:

```
mkdir folder
mdpdf filemd.md folder\filepdf.pdf
echo "table{border-collapse:collapse;}table,td,th{border:1px solid black;}" > table.css
pandoc -s filemd.md -c table.css -o ./folder/filehtml.html
del table.css
copy filemd.md export\filemd.md
cd folder
powershell Compress-Archive * Folder-Zip.zip
move Folder-Zip.zip ..\Folder-Zip.zip
cd ..
rmdir /Q /S folder
```

but after it's done I am left with a foler `"folder"` and inside a file named `"filepdf.pdf"`. I tried without the `mdpdf filemd.md folder\filepdf.pdf` and it ended up with a `"Folder-Zip.zip"` with inside it `"filemd.md" and "filehtml.html"`. What can I do, so I am left with a zip file named `"Folder-Zip.zip"` with inside of it `"filemd.md, filepdf.pdf and filehtml.html"`?

Comment: What's `mdpdf`? Is it an `.exe` or a `.bat`?

Comment: [mdpdf](https://npmjs.org/package/mdpdf) is installed via npm. It is a javascript file(node) - index.js. But when you install it (with `npm install mdpdf -g`) it puts a mdpdf.cmd file in `C:\Users\USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Roaming\npm`, and its contents are:
```batch
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0
IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)
"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\mdpdf\bin\index.js" %*
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b %errorlevel%
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
```

Comment: try `call mdpdf filemd.md ...` in the second line.

Comment: It worked! Thank you random internet man! You didn't do it as an answer, so I can't mark it as the correct one, but thank you!

Comment: no problem. It's a common issue and there are probably several dozens of similar questions here. By just executing a `.bat` or `.cmd`, you transfer control to it and it never returns. `call` returns when the called script ends.